# Calling GameScene.swift files through ViewController.swift files [Swift 3.0 Spritekit]

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have been trying to use `UIButton`s for a game interface, but I am still trying to figure out how to call methods that are inside a `GameScene` file through my view controller file. Is there anyway I can give my view controller a reference to the instance of the GameScene that is actually being displayed on the **GameScene.sks** file?

So far this is what I have tried in the view controller:

```
// Inside view controller
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    static var gameScene: GameScene = GameScene()

    func setGameScene(scene: GameScene) {
        GameViewController.gameScene = scene
    }
    ...
```

This is what I did in the GameScene file.

```
//Inside GameScene.swift
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let vc = GameViewController()
        vc.setGameScene(scene: self)
    }
...
```

Comment: Create an instance of SKView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a computed property to your view's scene

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    var gameScene : GameScene? { return (view as? SKView).scene as? GameScene}
    ...
}
```

Now this needs to be optional, because there may be times where your scene is not `GameScene`, and this could cause your app to crash.

Comment: Works very well! Thanks!